# Can I use the Web API & Play Button Widget for a 3rd Party Spotify Mobile App?

Tags: javascript, spotify, libspotify, spotify-app, despotify

I started building a Spotify Client for BlackBerry 10 using the Web API and the Play Button Widget but still have not published to the store since I want to clear up things first.

Please can anyone tell me if it's okay to use the Web API and the Play Button Widget in my 3rd Part Spotify Mobile App?

I use the Web API for authorization, loading playlists, tracks, albums etc, and I plan to use the Play Button Widget to play the full song.

I also plan to make money from it via Removing the Ads that I will integrate.

Link the the App's Details and Screenshots: http://forums.crackberry.com/blackberry-10-apps-f274/spo2fy-native-spotify-client-blackberry-10-a-948673/

Can somebody advise please?

Answer (score 2):

Right now the Developer Terms of Use forbid monetisation either directly or via adverts for applications that stream audio. The Developer ToS can be found [here](https://developer.spotify.com/developer-terms-of-use/).

Also, the Play Button widget doesn't work on mobile platforms like Blackberry - it requires a desktop machine as it remote controls either the Web Player or Desktop client.

Additionally, although not part of your question — your app looks like a direct copy of Spotify's own UI. In general, this isn't a good idea. This isn't a *threat* per se, but it's close enough to potentially look like an "official" client, which is also forbidden by the ToS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering everything sir. I thought I could make the Play Button work though but thanks. I have a more question, what if a developer violates the Terms? What will happen to them? Because I see a lot of 3rd Party Spotify Clients like this in google play, in the Ubuntu Phone OS.